# WPF DataContext issue with datacontext object

Tags: wpf

I have created a simple sample with datacontext. Please get the sample from here : [source](https://github.com/mathikp/DtSample) I understand that the uses of DataContext is

1. If the user change any content in UI, it should be updated in the back end datacontext class without any additional work.
2. If we make any change in back end datacontext object, it should be updated in UI without any additional work.

In my sample,

1. If I click "click" button, the textbox value gets updated. - pass
2. If I click "update" button, the textbox value gets updated. - pass
3. If I click "clear" button, the textbox value not updated. - fail
4. After clicked "clear" button, If "click" or "update" button is clicked the textbox value not updated. - fail

Am I doing anything wrong? If yes, how can I initialize some value in the textbox in constructor, and after that if the user make changes, the datacontext object values need to be updated. If I update any value in code behind, the values need to updated in UI. Also if I click "clear" button all the textbox values need to be cleared. After that if user enter value again, the object need to update. How can I achieve it? Please help.

*Note: In my sample I have commented some lines. In that i have casted the datacontext to the model class every time and changed it. Its working fine. Do i need to use that method to update values run time. Changing values in object will not update in UI?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you consider the variable 'dc' linked to the DataContext, but that is not the case. To fix your code simply set the DataContext again after you change the 'dc' variable.

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dc = new Journal();
        myPanel.DataContext = dc;
        //myPanel.DataContext = new Journal();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which means we need to set the datacontext again wherever we re-initialize the object with "new" keyword. Right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it is better to evaluate why you use the 'new' keyword, instead of creating a 'Reset' method in the viewmodel, and use that to reset your object. Than way there should be no need to use 'new'. BTW, if my answer solved your described issue, mark it as a solution, so other readers may use it in case they have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Id just like to add its usually a bad idea to completely replace a data context in use. It does work generally but there is a ton of overhead behind the scenes where all the bindings need to be renegotiate between the model and the UI. As @LupuSilviu said you are much better off using a method in the viewmodel to reset the data internally rather then building an entirely new viewmodel.